# How Can I filter Django Models based on lambda expression result?

Tags: django, django-models, filter

I know i could have used python's own functional tool-set, but I wish there's a way to this in Django.

I have this model:

```
class AssetGeoFenceEvent(models.Model):
#...
#assets, for which this event is assigned
asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset)
#...
```

and the referenced `Asset` model is like:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
#...
client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
#....
```

I thought I could do:

```
#get all the registered events for this client
events = AssetGeoFenceEvent.objects.filter(asset.client == client)
```

but that fails with error :

> keyword can't be an expression

Tried this but it fails:

```
#get all the registered events for this client
events = AssetGeoFenceEvent.objects.filter(lambda a: a.client == client)
```

Which gives me an error

> 'function' object is not iterable

So how can I pull this off using Django?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You're doing it wrong](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
events = AssetGeoFenceEvent.objects.filter(asset__client=client)
```